# Django's mark_for_escaping doesn't work with custom template tags?

Tags: django, django-1.4

I have a Django template tag that looks like this:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_for_escaping

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def hello_world(context):
    return mark_for_escaping("Hello, <world>!")
```

But when it's used in templates the output isn't being escaped.

What's going on? Is the output of template tags always assumed to be safe?

Comment: Does `return "{% autoescape on %}Hello, <world>!{% endautoescape %}"` work?

Comment: Also, what about `return escape("Hello, <world>!")`? (add `from django.utils.html import escape` import)

Comment: Explicitly escaping the result does work. I'm curious why `mark_for_escaping` seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: According to source, unlike filters (where it's configured via `needs_autoescape`), tags are not escaped.

Comment: Btw, can you pass `autoescape`: `True` in the context of the view and see if the tag will be escaped ? Thanks

Comment: And, sorry, to answer your previous questions: wrapping in "{% … %}" renders literal "{% … %}", and `context.autoescape` is `True`.